# How to display the same text from a textarea into another textarea and vice versa?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I make the three `textareas` in the sample below to show the same text at the same time by auto copying and updating the text from one another?

If I type in or change the text from `textarea 1` it should then auto copy/update all the text from `textarea 2` and `textarea 3` and vice versa? Right now it only seems to copy and update text from the `textarea 1`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#field_1').on('change', function (e) {
       $('#field_2').val($('#field_1').val());
        $('#field_3').val($('#field_1').val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea type='text' id='field_1'></textarea>
<textarea type='text' id='field_2'></textarea>
<textarea type='text' id='field_3'></textarea>
```

Been looking into this for some time and I cannot do it, so I will really appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do the trick:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  const ta = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');
  ta.forEach(t => {
    t.addEventListener('input', e => {
      ta.forEach(t => {
        t !== e.target && (t.value = e.target.value);
      });
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea type='text' id='field_1'></textarea>
<textarea type='text' id='field_2'></textarea>
<textarea type='text' id='field_3'></textarea>
```

Comment: Hello, this is so much appreciated. Just one question is, how do I exclude a textarea from this? Cause I have several more that I wouldn't want to copy these textareas?

Comment: just select the ones you need: `document.querySelectorAll('textarea.these-should-sync')`

Comment: I'm sorry but how do you that? Is it like ```document.querySelectorAll('textarea.field1, textarea.field2')```?

Comment: I also really like this solution, especially the real-time update without having to click the cursor anywhere else.

Comment: add a class to those you want to sync, say `class="sync"`, then select them like so: `document.querySelectorAll('textarea.sync')`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! Yayy!

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(':input').keyup(function (){
        $('#field_1').val($(this).val())
        $('#field_2').val($(this).val())
        $('#field_3').val($(this).val())
    });
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea type='text' id='field_1'></textarea>
<textarea type='text' id='field_2'></textarea>
<textarea type='text' id='field_3'></textarea>
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could work, capturing the change event, could also capture it on the body instead of aadding `sync_container` div.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById('sync_container').addEventListener('change', function(event){
        var element = event.target;
        var controls = element.getAttribute('aria-controls');
        if (controls) {
            controls = controls.split(' ');
            controls.forEach(function(id) {
                var next = document.getElementById(id);
                if (next) {
                    next.value = element.value;
                }
            });
        }
    }, true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sync_container">
    <textarea type='text' id='field_1' aria-controls='field_2 field_3'></textarea>
    <textarea type='text' id='field_2' aria-controls='field_1 field_3'></textarea>
    <textarea type='text' id='field_3' aria-controls='field_1 field_2'></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello! I really appreciate your help. But can you please tell me how to use this if my textareas cannot be grouped under one ```sync_container``` ```div```? Cause my other textareas are from different sets. I really like this solution.

Comment: Just change this `document.getElementById('sync_container')` to this: `document.body`

Answer (score 1):

Easy, with vanilla js as it is lighter.

```js
// First create array with elements
let allTextAreas = [...document.querySelectorAll('textarea')];

allTextAreas.forEach(textArea=>{
  // For each element, add input listener
  textArea.addEventListener('click', ({target: {value}})=>{
    // On input, update all other elements
    allTextAreas
      .filter(item=>item!=textArea)
      .forEach(item=>{
        item.value = value;
      })
  })
})
```

```html
<textarea type='text' id='field_1'></textarea>
<textarea type='text' id='field_2'></textarea>
<textarea type='text' id='field_3'></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

we can use Proxy to watch the changes and update all the text Areas

```js
    let field1 = document.getElementById("field_1");
    let field2 = document.getElementById("field_2");
    let field3 = document.getElementById("field_3");
    const data = {
        value: ''
    };
    const handler = {
        set(target, key, value) {
            field1.value = field2.value = field3.value = value;
        }
    };
    
    const proxy = new Proxy(data, handler);
    field1.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
        proxy.value = event.target.value;
        console.log(event.target.value);
    });
    field2.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
        proxy.value = event.target.value;
        console.log(event.target.value);
    });
    field3.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
        proxy.value = event.target.value;
        console.log(event.target.value);
    });
```

```html
<textarea type='text' id='field_1'></textarea>
<textarea type='text' id='field_2'></textarea>
<textarea type='text' id='field_3'></textarea>
```